# How to I retrieve data from a Relation in a top-level object retrieved from parse.com using PHP

Tags: php, curl, relational-database, parse-platform

I am attempting to retrieve data from a `Relation` using [parse.com](http://parse.com) and PHP

I get the top-leve object without problem but I can't access related data. (`[myRelation] => stdClass Object ( [__type] => Relation [className] => other`))

Please refer to my code below:

```
$className = "myClass";
$url = 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/' . $className;
$appId = 'xxxxxx'; 
$restKey = 'xxxxxxx';

$relatedParams = urlencode('include=people'); 
$rest = curl_init(); curl_setopt($rest, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 curl_setopt($rest, CURLOPT_URL, $url .'/io1GzkzErH/'.$relatedParams); 
curl_setopt($rest, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true); 
curl_setopt($rest, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); curl_setopt($rest, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,

array("X-Parse-Application-Id: " . $appId,
    "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: " . $restKey,
    "Content-Type: application/json"));
$response = curl_exec($rest); 
echo $response;
```

---

The full response from the `$echo` is below:

```
stdClass Object ( 
         [Altres] => 
                loremipsum.      
         [Categoria] => 
                Comedia 
         [Durada] => 
                120min 
         [Estat] => 
                Al teatre 

        [createdAt] => 
                2014-05-20T12:01:06.094Z 
        [objectId] => 
                 io1GzkzErH 
        [people] => 
                stdClass Object ( 
                              [__type] => 
                                     Relation [className] => 
                                                          persones )
         [updatedAt] => 
                   2014-05-20T12:07:22.758Z )
```

How do I access properties in the `Relation [className] => persones` from this example section?

```
[people] => 
    stdClass Object ( 
        [__type] => 
            Relation [className] => persones )
```

Comment: @Albeet I think you are halfway there. Please list exactly what you have done(Your close on this part), what you'd expect to see, and what you are actually seeing instead(errors, etc.). Just post that directly as edits to your question.

Comment: Thank you @nsfyn55 , post already edited with parse response

Comment: Thanks for coming back. I think if you took a little time to format that response you might have some better luck.

Comment: Sorry @nsfyn55 , i'm not acquainted with editor. I think that now is more friendly.

Comment: awesome man. It looks like its in good shape. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Excerpt from the parse.com documentation

> If you want to retrieve objects that are members of Relation field of a parent object, you can use the $relatedTo operator. Imagine you have a Post class and User class, where each Post can be liked by many users. If the Users that liked a Post was stored in a Relation on the post under the key likes, you, can the find the users that liked a particular post by:

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: ${APPLICATION_ID}" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ${REST_API_KEY}" \
  -G \
  --data-urlencode 'where={"$relatedTo":{"object":
{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Post","objectId":"8TOXdXf3tz"},"key":"likes"}}' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/users
```

### Explanation

parse.com's api is a bit strange. Your objects are arranged in `many-to-one` relationship in this case `people<persones>->class<Class>`. You need to query with a `where` clause to the api endpoint of of the class that represents the `one` and use a `$relatedTo` operator. When you use the `$relatedTo` operator you will specify an `objectId` that uniquely identifies an entity on the **one** side of the relationship and a `key` that indicates the **many** side. Its very similar to a join in `SQL`

### The query below should work for you:

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: ${APPLICATION_ID}" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ${REST_API_KEY}" \
  -G \
  --data-urlencode 'where={"$relatedTo":{"object":
{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Class","objectId":"io1GzkzErH"},"key":"people"}}' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I put that in curl, parse show me:{"code":102,"error":"wrong type of relation. Expecting: , but recieved: persones"}.

and if I delete: "className":"persones" , the error is
 
{"code":102,"error":"a valid pointer is needed for RelatedTo operator"}.

Comment: what is the class name of the object's in the `people` relationship

Comment: classname is "persones"

Comment: There was a typo the className should be whatever the class is of your top-level object.

Comment: REQUEST PARAMS-->urlencode('where={"$relatedTo":{"object":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"persones","objectId":"sEjqosnSCY"},"key":"people"}}'); <br/>
ANSWER-->{"code":102,"error":"wrong type of relation. Expecting: , but recieved: espectacles"} .

---------------------------------------------------------------------
REQUEST--> urlencode('where={"$relatedTo":{"object":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"espectacles","objectId":"sEjqosnSCY"},"key":"people"}}');

ANSWER --> {"code":102,"error":"wrong type of relation. Expecting: persones, but recieved: espectacles"} .

----------

Comment: Ok! it's running changing the classname of the url. Thank you so much!